# Symfony2 Payum Abstract Methods

Tags: php, oop, symfony, abstract-class, abstract

I'm using [payumbundle](https://github.com/Payum/Payum) on my website but in my prod server (in dev server everything works fine) i get this error:

> FatalErrorException: Compile Error: Can't inherit abstract function Payum\Request\StatusRequestInterface::getModel() (previously declared abstract in Payum\Request\ModelRequestInterface) in /path/to/folder/vendor/payum/payum/src/Payum/Request/BinaryMaskStatusRequest.php line 5

Here is the code at vendor/payum/payum/src/Payum/Request/BinaryMaskStatusRequest.php at line 5

```
class BinaryMaskStatusRequest extends BaseModelInteractiveRequest implements StatusRequestInterface {
```

in my development server i have PHP 5.3.10 while in prod server i have PHP 5.3.3.

Comment: Do you have any abstract methods in `BinaryMaskStatusRequest` ?

Comment: Actually i commented Payum\Request\StatusRequestInterface::getModel() function, but i'm pretty sure that this isn't the right way to fix it

Comment: No abstract methods in BinaryMaskStatusRequest.

Comment: Does `BaseModelInteractiveRequest` contain any abstract methods, that aren't overriden in `BinaryMaskStatusRequest` ?

Comment: `BaseModelInteractiveRequest` does not contain any abstract method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Actually i commented Payum\Request\StatusRequestInterface::getModel() function, but i'm pretty sure that this isn't the right way to fix it

Nice catch! I will remove these methods (getModel and setModel) on StatusRequestInterface interface. They come from previous version and should not be there any longer. The bad thing is I can remove them only since version 0.6 as it introduce BC break.